# get mongoDB embedded document array value using php?

Tags: php, mongodb

How to get the contact values?, and How are the values stored in php?

```
 {

 _id : "001",

 name : "fakename",

 contact_address : {

                    street : "12 Street",

                    city : "Cosmos",

                    contact : [ 
                               "123456789",
                               "012345678" 
                              ]

                   }
}
```

Query :

```
$cursor = $collection->find ( array('name' => 'fakename' ), array( 'contact_address.contact' ) );

   foreach ( $cursor as $doc ) {

         echo $doc[ 'contact_address' ][ 'contact' ];
   }
```

**Result :**

```
 Array
```

**Motive :** Intend to print the contact values.

Comment: echo does not print arrays. Use print_r, or iterate values with foreach or other method of preference.

Comment: @vuryss Only the values required, with print_r the indices are printed alongside.

Comment: Then use a simple foreach. Like `foreach ($doc['contact_address']['contact'] as $item) echo $item`

Comment: Thanks! it worked.

Comment: You must post this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

To print array values you can use `print_r`, `var_dump` or `var_export` - for debugging purposes.

To iterate them and use values in other places - you can use for example `foreach` like that:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    // $key holds the index, $value holds the value of the array
}
```

There are other ways to iterate array, in fact way too many in PHP, but this should suffice.